# Spring: Can't move @Transactioanl annotation from DAO to Service layer

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactional

It the Transactional annotation is in the DAO layer it works, if I move it to the service layer, I get exception:

```
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.adam.czibere.RestAPIController]: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Here is my code:

**CatalogDAOInterface:**

```
public interface CatalogDAOInterface {

    public List<Product> getAllProduct();

    public List<Category> getAllCategories() ;

    public List<Media> getAllMedias();

}
```

**CatalogDAO:**

```
@Repository
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
public class CatalogDAO implements CatalogDAOInterface {

     @Autowired private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


     @Override
     public List<Product> getAllProduct() {
             Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
             List products = session.createQuery("from Product").list();
             return products;
     }

     @Override
     public List<Category> getAllCategories() {
             Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
             List products = session.createQuery("from Category").list();
             return products;
     }

     @Override
     public List<Media> getAllMedias() {
             Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
             List medias = session.createQuery("from Media").list();
             return medias;
     }   

}
```

**CatalogServiceInterface:**

```
public interface CatalogServiceInterface {

    public List<Category> getAllCategories();
    public List<Product> getAllProducts();
    public List<Media> getAllMedias();

}
```

**CatalogService:**

```
@Service
public class CatalogService implements CatalogServiceInterface{

    @Autowired
    private CatalogDAO catalogDAO;

        @Transactinal
    @Override
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        return catalogDAO.getAllProduct();
    }

        @Transactinal
    @Override
    public List<Category> getAllCategories() {
        return catalogDAO.getAllCategories();
    }

        @Transactinal
    @Override
    public List<Media> getAllMedias() {
        return catalogDAO.getAllMedias();
    }

}
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Enable @Controller annotation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.adam.czibere" />

<!--    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" -->
<!--        destroy-method="close"> -->
<!--        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> -->
<!--        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pizzashop" /> -->
<!--        <property name="username" value="root" /> -->
<!--        <property name="password" value="czadam" /> -->
<!--        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" /> -->
<!--    </bean> -->

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://something" />
        <property name="username" value="something" />
        <property name="password" value="something" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
    <bean id="mySessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array>
                <value>com.adam.czibere</value>
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

**The stack trace:**

```
exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)


root cause 

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'catalogAPIController' defined in file [C:\Users\czadam\Documents\workspace 2.0\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\SalesWizard\WEB-INF\classes\com\adam\czibere\CatalogAPIController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.adam.czibere.CatalogAPIController]: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)


root cause 

org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.adam.czibere.CatalogAPIController]: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:158)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:110)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)


root cause 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:110)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

**Part of My Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "api", produces = "application/json")
public class CatalogAPIController {

    CatalogService catalogService;

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    @Autowired
    public CatalogAPIController(CatalogService catalogService) {
        this.catalogService = catalogService;
    }

    // get all categories
    @RequestMapping(value = "category/all", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getAllCategories() {
        JSONArray categoryArray = new JSONArray();
        for (Category cat : catalogService.getAllCategories()) {
            JSONObject categoryJSON = new JSONObject();
            try {
                categoryJSON.put("id", cat.getId());
                categoryJSON.put("name", cat.getName());

                categoryJSON.put("imageMediaID", cat.getImageMediaID());
                categoryJSON.put("parentID", cat.getParent().getId());

                // Media
                JSONArray mediaArray = new JSONArray();
                for (Media item : cat.getMedias()) {
                    if (item != null) {

                        mediaArray.put(item.getId());
                    }
                }
                categoryJSON.put("mediaIDs", mediaArray);

                categoryJSON.put("modifiedDate", cat.getModifiedDate());

                categoryArray.put(categoryJSON);
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
            }

        }
        return categoryArray.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stack trace and your `RestAPIController` class.

Comment: When you add the `@Transactional` annotations to your service class, Spring will inject a proxy into your `RestAPIController` rather than an instance of the real service. That may be causing the `IllegalArgumentException` but as Sotirios says, post both the stacktrace and controller code so we can get a bit more info.

Comment: I posted the stack trace and teh controler.

Answer (score 6):

When Spring is applying the `@Transactional` annotation internally, it creates a proxy class which wraps your service class.

So when your service bean is created in your application context, you are getting an object that is not of type `CatalogService` but some `Proxy$1` class.

This `Proxy$1` class will not extend `CatalogService` but it will implement `CatalogServiceInterface`.  Therefore, when your `CatalogAPIController` bean gets created, it attempts to call its constructor with your `Proxy$1` object which is the wrong type as your constructor expects a class.

So if you were to change your controller to use the interface instead of the implementation, then I believe your problems will disappear.  This is because `Proxy$1` DOES implement `CatalogServiceInterface`.

The moral of the story:  ALWAYS use the interface if you reference your implementation (for if you ever decide to provide a different implementation (e.g. `CatalogService2` which also implements `CatalogServiceInterface`, you can only plug that into your `CatalogAPIController` if its constructor is using the interface rather than the class (and essentially this is what's happening when you specify `@Transactional`.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

two thing caught my attention

1.

```
@Transactinal
```

is it a typo or are you importing another annotation, it should be @Transactional

2.

why aren't you using the interfaces if you're already defining them?

instead of

```
@Autowired
public CatalogAPIController(CatalogService catalogService) {
    this.catalogService = catalogService;
}
```

change it to

```
@Autowired
public CatalogAPIController(CatalogServiceInterface catalogService) {
    this.catalogService = catalogService;
}
```

same applies to dao interface.

I don't understand the relation between moving transactional from one place to the other. See if that helps

Answer (score 0):

This is what I can think of with the details you've provided. I believe you don't have the `CGLIB` libraries on your classpath. As such, for Spring to apply `@Transactional` behavior, it proxies your annotated class with JDK proxies. JDK proxies use interfaces, they cannot proxy base classes. As such, the direct superclass of a proxy is [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).

In this case, your `CatalogService` bean will be wrapped in a proxy whose class is something like `Proxy$1`. When Spring tries to instantiate your `@Controller` class, `CatalogAPIController`, through reflection using the constructor

```
@Autowired
public CatalogAPIController(CatalogService catalogService) {
    this.catalogService = catalogService;
}
```

it will fail because the argument passed to the [`Constructor#newInstance(Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) method will not match the parameter type `CatalogService` since `Proxy$1` is not a sub type of `CatalogService`.

The reason this didn't happen when you were annotating the DAO, I believe is that your DAO class is not on the `component-scan` package that applied `@Transactional` behavior. So it might have appeared as though the `@Transactional` was working but it wasn't. Because `@Transactional` wasn't working, no proxy was created and therefore Spring didn't complain about injecting this field

```
@Autowired
private CatalogDAO catalogDAO;
```

in your service class.

One possible solution is to do what Luis recommended and change your parameter types to the interface as JDK proxies to implement the interfaces, ie. the interfaces are supertypes of the `Proxy$1` class instance generated to wrap your bean.

Another solution is to provide the `CGLIB` jars on your classpath. Spring will detect them and use them. It will then be able to proxy your class by base class instead of interface. [You can find the libraries here.](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cglib/cglib)

Don't forget to tell Spring to proxy the target class with

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
```